# Cannot import compiler/typescript.ts

Tags: typescript

The one line program helloworld

```
///<reference path='/Users/tadams/git/typescript/src/compiler/typescript.ts'/>
```

breaks typescript-0.9.0

the error is 
bash-3.2$ tsc helloworld.ts

```
/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:42270
                comparisonInfo.flags |= 128 /* InconsistantPropertyAccesib
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
at PullTypeResolver.sourcePropertyIsRelatableToTargetProperty (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:42270:35)
at PullTypeResolver.sourceMembersAreRelatableToTargetMembers (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:42243:27)
at PullTypeResolver.sourceIsRelatableToTarget (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:42183:46)
at PullTypeResolver.sourceIsAssignableToTarget (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:42003:25)
at PullTypeResolver.computeCallExpressionSymbol (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:41007:51)
at PullTypeResolver.resolveCallExpression (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:40891:29)
at PullTypeChecker.typeCheckCallExpression (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:44820:58)
at PullTypeChecker.typeCheckAST (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:43506:33)
at PullTypeChecker.typeCheckReturnStatement (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:45394:35)
at PullTypeChecker.typeCheckAST (/Users/tadams/git/typescript/bin/tsc.js:43639:33)
```

Does anybody know what's going on or what this error message means?  Running typescript-0.9.0 on Mac OS X 10.8.  Thanks!

UPDATE:
  There was a bug in typescript .9.  A method were not called with enough arguments which lead to this strange bug.  Here's the bug patch diff.

```
diff --git a/src/compiler/typecheck/pullTypeResolution.ts b/src/compiler/typecheck/pullTypeResolution.ts
index ec3d236..801ed2f 100644
--- a/src/compiler/typecheck/pullTypeResolution.ts
+++ b/src/compiler/typecheck/pullTypeResolution.ts
@@ -4001,7 +4001,7 @@ module TypeScript {
                     getTypeAtIndex: (index: number) => { return rightType; } // we only want the "second" type - the "first" is skipped
                 }

-                var bestCommonType = this.findBestCommonType(leftType, null, collection, context);
+                var bestCommonType = this.findBestCommonType(leftType, null, collection, context, new TypeComparisonInfo());

                 if (bestCommonType) {
                     symbol = bestCommonType;
@@ -6442,7 +6442,7 @@ module TypeScript {
                         setTypeAtIndex: (index: number, type: PullTypeSymbol) => { } , // no contextual typing here, so no need to do anything
                          getTypeAtIndex: (index: number) => { return index ?     Q.signature.getReturnType() : best.signature.getReturnType(); } // we only want the "second" type  - the "first" is skippe
                     }
    -                    var bct = this.findBestCommonType(best.signature.getReturnType(), null, collection, context);
    +                    var bct = this.findBestCommonType(best.signature.getReturnType(), null,    collection, context, new TypeComparisonInfo());
                     ambiguous = !bct;
                 }
                 else {
    @@ -6844,4 +6844,4 @@ module TypeScript {
             return sig;
         }
     }
    -}
    \ No newline at end of file
    +}`
```

Comment: are you trying to compile the compiler i.e. typescript.ts[https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/compiler/typescript.ts]?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all of the dependencies are available, in particular in your example I would imagine `flags.ts`:

Here are all the dependencies of `typescript.ts`

```
///<reference path='diagnostics.ts' />
///<reference path='flags.ts' />
///<reference path='nodeTypes.ts' />
///<reference path='hashTable.ts' />
///<reference path='ast.ts' />
///<reference path='astWalker.ts' />
///<reference path='astWalkerCallback.ts' />
///<reference path='astPath.ts' />
///<reference path='astLogger.ts' />
///<reference path='binder.ts' />
///<reference path='base64.ts' />
///<reference path='sourceMapping.ts' />
///<reference path='emitter.ts' />
///<reference path='errorReporter.ts' />
///<reference path='parser.ts' />
///<reference path='printContext.ts' />
///<reference path='scanner.ts' />
///<reference path='scopeAssignment.ts' />
///<reference path='scopeWalk.ts' />
///<reference path='signatures.ts' />
///<reference path='symbols.ts' />
///<reference path='symbolScope.ts' />
///<reference path='tokens.ts' />
///<reference path='typeChecker.ts' />
///<reference path='typeCollection.ts' />
///<reference path='typeFlow.ts' />
///<reference path='types.ts' />
///<reference path='pathUtils.ts' />
///<reference path='referenceResolution.ts' />
///<reference path='precompile.ts' />
///<reference path='incrementalParser.ts' />
///<reference path='declarationEmitter.ts' />
```

I have also seen in the past problems caused by comments that aren't formatted exactly right. I recommend always putting a space before the closing slash (even though I don't think this is the problem in your case), i.e.

```
///<reference path='/Users/tadams/git/typescript/src/compiler/typescript.ts' />
```

Not

```
///<reference path='/Users/tadams/git/typescript/src/compiler/typescript.ts'/>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.

tsc flags.ts works fine.

typescript.ts has flags and flags is in the same folder.  

It seems to happen with other files in the compiler but I haven't seen it with files elsewhere.  Perhaps I can't reference the compiler?  I'm going to investigate this.

Comment: This does not seem to be it.  Copying the file and updating its references had no effect on the bug.